# backpack n-n relation error on adding record

Tags: php, laravel, relationship, laravel-backpack

https://laravel-backpack.readme.io/v3.0/docs/newscrud

I follow this code to make n-n relation
but when i add a new record to the subscriptions (articles in the example) table i get an error

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'name' doesn't have a
>   default value (SQL: insert into features (updated_at, created_at)
>   values (2019-02-25 07:21:45, 2019-02-25 07:21:45))

this is the error >> featuers table is (tags table in the example)
but should not create on it is should create the record in the subscription_feature table (article_tag in the example)

Comment: The error clearly says that name field doesn't have a default value. So it means you're not feeding a name value from the submit request + if you want name optional change the schema for name field to `DEFAULT NULL` in table.

Comment: it shouldn't add at this table actually  .. it should insert in this table (subscription_feature)

Comment: Can you share your full code please?

Comment: thank you for your interest ... I've solved it I just forget to add 'pivot' => true, in the Field function... thank you a lot

Comment: Good work. Glad to know :)